# Broken GRUB bootloader!

Tags: grub2

So, I decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS onto a seperate partition on my HDD. While "trying" to repair a USB drive in windows partition manager, I accidently deleted the Ubuntu partition. Now, when I reboot, I get the error "no such partition" because it is looking for Ubuntu. It then sends me to the rescue prompt. The only thing I can do is have a laptop with no HDD using Ubuntu off of a USB stick, while a SATA to USB adapter attached to the laptop. I can access the drive, but all I want to do is to repair GRUB. I CAN'T USE BOOT REPAIR BECAUSE I DON'T GET A RECCOMENDED REPAIR OPTION. Is there any easy way to remove grub?

Comment: Do you want the Windows MBR back or GRUB2 fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

- Reinstall Ubuntu
- revert to the standard loader of Windows

---

- If you choose option 1 reinstall Ubuntu alongside Windows
- but, you want to remove grub, so follow the steps below

---

1. Find the Windows installation media use used to install Windows.
2. Set the boot priority to that media by going to setup utility when you start the PC
3. Boot the PC with that installation media
4. When Windows setup loads up, choose "Repair your computer".
5. Click on Troubleshoot on the Choose an option page
6. Then, Advanced Options -----> Command Prompt
7. Type bootrec.exe /fixmbr and hit enter key
8. Reboot the PC and go back to the setup utility, set the boot priority to your hard drive and reboot

See if you can boot Windows normally.

Comment: Ok, I fixed GRUB. But now when I boot into Windows 7 Home edition (HE) I finish the "window assembly screen" and then it just reboots... Ubuntu works just fine though.

Comment: What you mean by Window assembly screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting with windows bootable media, like USB or DVD, then choose option to repair.
 Go for start up repair, and if it won't find any problem, open cdm while still using windows bootable media, and type the following commands

```
bootrec/fixmbr 
bootrec/fixboot
```

That should work.
If you are using win xp use `fixmbr` command instead.

Also, you can try with ubuntu live cd. Just select try ubuntu without installing, after it loads, open the terminal and type the following command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

You must have internet for Ubuntu option, though it doesn't need a lot of data.